# Unable to SELECT .all() using SeaORM - the trait `ConnectionTrait` is not implemente

Tags: postgresql, rust, orm, actix-web, sea-orm

Getting the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Data<DatabaseConnection>: ConnectionTrait` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:27:34
    |
27  |     let q = Articles::find().all(&data).await;
    |                              --- ^^^^^ the trait `ConnectionTrait` is not implemented for `Data<DatabaseConnection>`
    |                              |
    |                              required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `ConnectionTrait`:
              DatabaseConnection
              DatabaseTransaction
note: required by a bound in `sea_orm::executor::select::<impl sea_orm::Select<E>>::all`
   --> /Users//.cargo/registry/src/git/sea-orm-0.10.6/src/executor/select.rs:267:12
    |
267 |         C: ConnectionTrait,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `sea_orm::executor::select::<impl sea_orm::Select<E>>::all`
```

main.rs:

```
async fn test(data: web::Data<DatabaseConnection>) -> HttpResponse {
    dbg!(&data);

    let q = Articles::find().all(&data).await;

    HttpResponse::Ok().json("test")
}

async fn get_connection() -> DatabaseConnection {
    Database::connect("postgres://...")
        .await
        .expect("Failed to connect to database!")
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let db = get_connection().await;

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .service(web::resource("/").route(web::get().to(test)))
            .app_data(web::Data::new(db.clone()))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8888))?
    .run()
    .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `all` being generic is preventing deref coercion from kicking in here - if you do `&*data` (or `data.get_ref()`) instead of `&data` it might work?

Comment: @JoeClay `.get_ref()` works. `&*` also doesn't. How come in all the implementations I've seen on github everyone's just using `&`. Am I doing something wrong?